# Parse text file with addresses, byte values, and comments to binary file

Tags: xxd

I'm attempting to start with a file in the following form:

```
00: 42 ; byte 0 is 0x42 / d
01: 52 ; byte 1 is 0x52 / r
02: 62 ; byte 2 is 0x62 / D
03: 72 ; byte 3 is 0x72 / R
07: 1f ; bytes 03..0e are implicitly 00, byte 0f is 0x1f
```

and use it to generate an 8-byte file whose values (in hex form) would be:

`42 52 62 72 00 00 00 1f`

The exact input format isn't carved in stone. I just picked ';' as a comment delimiter because it's a single character and unambiguous. The form of the offset: and 2-digit hex value just seemed obvious based on tradition.

I suspect the ultimate solution involves using `sed` or `awk` to strip away the comment, then piping their output to `xxd`, but so far my first experiment has fallen flat on its face & I can't even get xxd to parse what ought to be a best-case simple text file.

---

For my first attempt, I simplified config.src:

```
00: 42
01: 52
02: 62
03: 72
```

(omitting the comments and implied zero-bytes for now, and sticking to values corresponding to printable ASCII)

... then tried to generate the binary file from it:

`xxd -r config.src config.bin`

What I expected to see from `cat config.bin` and `xxd config.bin`:

`BRbr` and `00000000: 42 52 62 72 BRbr`

What I ended up with:

a 2-byte file with unprintable content `cat` can't render, and the following output from `xxd config.bin`: `00000000: 0301`

So... problem #1... *What am I doing wrong with xxd*, and how can I fix it (or is there a better approach)? Keep in mind that I really want to specify one byte value per line, and would really like to be able to automatically skip sequential values and have them automatically filled with zeroes.

The... problem #2... once I get xxd to parse my file, how can I go add the comments and strip them away before xxd sees them?

Note that I'm not hellbent on using xxd per se... but this is a shared web server to which I don't have root or admin access, so `apt-get install` isn't an option, and compiling my own copies from source wouldn't necessarily be easy).

---

*(Background info... not necessary essential to solving the problem, but adding context to why I'm trying to do it)*

I'm working on an Arduino-based IoT controller. For the past few weeks, its configuration has consisted of hardcoded values and various interpretations of a DIP switch I've repurposed every few days. It's getting tedious. I'm not in the mood yet to implement a proper UI, so I came up with the idea of having it just fetch a binary config blob from my web server into a char[] as its first act upon starting up (enabling me to tweak runtime config values without having to go all the way and reflash the board itself, which is honestly kind of a pain at this point).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's start with your `config.src`:

```
$ cat config.src
00: 42 ; byte 0 is 0x42 / d
01: 52 ; byte 1 is 0x52 / r
02: 62 ; byte 2 is 0x62 / D
03: 72 ; byte 3 is 0x72 / R
07: 1f ; bytes 03..0e are implicitly 00, byte 0f is 0x1f
```

Convert it to `config.bin`, comments are skipped by `-c1`:

```
$ xxd -r -c1 config.src config.bin
$ xxd config.bin
00000000: 4252 6272 0000 001f                      BRbr....
```

Convert it back to the `config.src` format:

```
$ xxd -c1 config.bin # this is unmodified
00000000: 42  B
00000001: 52  R
00000002: 62  b
00000003: 72  r
00000004: 00  .
00000005: 00  .
00000006: 00  .
00000007: 1f  .
$ xxd -c1 config.bin | awk -F '' '
  {
    $0=substr($0, 7)    # remove 6 leading characters
    $0=substr($0, 1, 6) # remove ASCII output
  }
  /00$/{ next }      # skip hex 00
  { print $0 " ; " } # print line and empty comment
'
00: 42 ;
01: 52 ;
02: 62 ;
03: 72 ;
07: 1f ;
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try perl's `pack` function.

- [perlpacktut](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlpacktut.html)

Ex. given

```
$ cat config.src
00: 42 ; byte 0 is 0x42 / d
01: 52 ; byte 1 is 0x52 / r
02: 62 ; byte 2 is 0x62 / D
03: 72 ; byte 3 is 0x72 / R
07: 1f ; bytes 03..0e are implicitly 00, byte 0f is 0x1f
```

then

```
$ perl -ne 'm/(\d+): ([[:xdigit:]]{2})/; while($n++ < $1){print pack("x")}; print pack("H*",$2)' config.src | xxd -c1
00000000: 42  B
00000001: 52  R
00000002: 62  b
00000003: 72  r
00000004: 00  .
00000005: 00  .
00000006: 00  .
00000007: 1f  .
```